# Printing an int array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I can't come up with an idea on why the array is printing out the int's in order instead of the order that they're put in the array.

```
int[] array = {1, 4, 0, 3, 2};
for(int i : array){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Is there any explanation of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the `i` does not represent the index, it´s rather a value returned by the `Iterator` and the current element of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be printing the loop's variable :

```
for(int i : array){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

If you print `array[i]` instead of `i`, you get 4 instead of 1 as the first printed element, since `array[1] == 4`.

Your code would be correct if you were using the traditional for loop, which iterates over the indices of the array :

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: you beat me to speed. Your int i here is not equivalent to an index. It's your current integer value being read.

Comment: I just came in this, and he posted.